# Show / hide image depends on date

Tags: javascript, php, date

I'm looking to display a different image (a zodiac sign image) on my website based on the date of the year. For example : between 21 march to 21 april will display the "Aries" image, Between 22 april to 21 may will display the "Taurus" image, etc.
I'm looking for a simple code or script to do it in PHP or JS. Didn't find nothing on internet like that.

Thanx for you help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just google zodiac dates js, you get your solution easily

and you can build your own quite easily.

this is one of the simplest

```js
const signs = ['Aries: The Ram','Taurus: The Bull','Gemini: The Twins','Cancer: The Crab','Leo: The Lion','Virgo: The Virgin','Libra: The Scales','Scorpio: The Scorpion','Sagittarius: The Archer','Capricorn: The Goat','Aquarius: The Water Bearer','Pisces: The Fish'];

var sign = Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-TN-u-ca-persian', {month: 'numeric'}).format(Date.now())) - 1;
document.getElementById('sign').innerHTML  = signs[sign]
console.log(signs[sign]);
```

```html
    <h1>
      the value for this month sign is: <span id="sign"></span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer Ahmed, this snippet seems perfect... but i'm not developer, so, i don't understand how to display the "console.log" in html. The document.write() didn't seems to work.

Comment: if you share your html,  where you want to display it, then i can tell you

Comment: Here you go : https://codepen.io/vincent-dassens/pen/NWNpdxp

Comment: i have updated the answer with your codepen code , check now

Comment: It work perfectly now, thank you very much Ahmed. The last step for me is too replace each text array sign with an image. Thanx again.